# Solder Flux Classifications

Tags: soldering, flux

I was at Fry's yesterday, looking for some thin solder to use on an Adafruit kit with through-hole components.

Two of the solders I found were labeled *RA Flux* and *No Clean*, respectively. An engineer who was present said that with my use-case I should choose *No Clean*, as I wouldn't need to clean the board afterwards.

**Can anyone clarify how one should select solder based on flux type?**  I had always been under the impression that you just use some sort of (one size fits all?) rosin-core solder with for basic board work, so I was confused at the different flux labels.  I didn't think you had to clean your board (although I do know that after soldering yellow gunk can be left behind, and I suspect this is a flux by-product).  I also know that you should avoid solder with an acidic core for electronics work, as that is for pipes + household plumbing.

---

The wikipedia page for soldering classifies many of the different [types of fluxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldering#Flux), most of which require cleaning:

- R (non-activated)
- RMA (mildly-activated)
- RA (activated)
- No Clean

**Can someone explain why/how you should choose a flux type for a given application?**  Most of the answers below answer "what."  I'd like to learn a bit of the theory.

Answer (score 16):

For thru-hole work (which it sounds like you are doing) I would go with an active 
flux that is water soluble. You need to wash the residue off since it is corrosive 
and can cause shorts. I have had a number of boards mysteriously come back to life after
a good cleaning.

For thru-hole parts that may get damaged by cleaning (LED lenses) or SMD parts
with heatsink pads I would use the no clean flux.

I have been using the flux pens from Kester. 2331-ZX for water soluble flux and
the 951 for no-clean. To clean the water soluble flux I use an "acid" brush with
the bristles clipped to around 0.5". I run the board under the hottest tap water
I get (probably around 140-160degF) and scrub with the brush. If I do a small
repair job I will clean with the isopropyl alcohol I have on my bench.

Here some of the whys --

Why you need flux -- to get a quality joint at a lower soldering temperature.
  Using a liquid flux lets you spread the flux better over the two surfaces
  to be soldered.

Why choose an aggressive flux -- an aggresive flux is more tolerant of soldering
 temperatures. As Leon mentioned this would be a good candidate for a hobbyist.
 I like the 2331-ZX for this. Since these leave ionic compounds you need to clean.

Why choose no-clean -- eliminates a process step and the issues associated with
 the extra process step. For example for soldering XLamp LEDs I use a no-clean
 flux rather than risk scratching the lens.

For more details take a look at http://www.finishing.com/Library/flux.html
and the Kester website.

Comment: At my job some rosin flux was the problem behind a TX antenna mismatching, we now use water based flux. to clean it we give the board a good rinse and then dry it with compressed air.

Answer (score 8):

RA flux contains activated rosin, and is the most active flux. It's probably more suitable for hobbyists as it'll be easier to get good joints. Use 99% isopropyl alcohol for removing it.

Comment: do not have isopropyl alcohol around so using paint-removal-spray for car-industry or acetone, to remove extra rosin. Spay rosin-blackened spot and then just rinse with water. Probably cheaper than electronics spays as bottles are bigger.

Comment: Where do you get IPA?

Comment: IPA is commonly available (at least in the US) in drugstores. Look for the 99% type. Electronics stores often also carry anhydrous (99.9%), but it is a bit more expensive.

Comment: In the US it's also referred to as "rubbing alcohol".

Comment: Be cautious if soldering optocouplers. Avago recommends [against](https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/AV02-4463EN) the use of halide-containing fluxes (e.g. RA flux) with plastic optocouplers, because the halides can migrate into the optocoupler packages and damage the components.

Comment: @hhh do not recommend acetone. It is too aggressive. It will damage plastic parts on the PCB..